# Swapping buffers with core profile uses invalid operations

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glfw, freeglut

Whenever I call a function to swap buffers I get tons of errors from `glDebugMessageCallback` saying:

> glVertex2f has been removed from OpenGL Core context (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)

I've tried using both with GLFW and freeglut, and neither work appropriately.

I haven't used `glVertex2f`, of course. I even went as far as to delete all my rendering code to see if I can find what's causing it, but the error is still there, right after `glutSwapBuffers`/`glfwSwapBuffers`.
Using single-buffering causes no errors either.

I've initialized the context to 4.3, core profile, and flagged forward-compatibility.

Comment: An interesting thought occurs to me... many pieces of software that insert overlays in OpenGL applications (e.g. Steam, FRAPS, etc.) do so by hooking into the swap buffer operation. They will inject a few extra lines of code every time your application swaps buffers. Are you using any third-party software like that? It could be using legacy OpenGL to try and overlay some text.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes! I was using Afterburner's RivaTuner HUD. Please write this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in comments, the problem here is actually third-party software and not any code you yourself wrote.

When software such as the Steam overlay or FRAPS need to draw something overtop OpenGL they usually go about this by hooking/injecting some code into your application's `SwapBuffers` implementation at run-time.

You are dealing with a piece of software (RivaTuner) that still uses immediate mode to draw its overlay and that is the source of the unexplained deprecated API calls on every buffer swap.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code you can share? Either the driver is buggy or something tries to call glVertex in your process. You could try to use glloadgen to build a loader library that covers OpenGL-4.3 symbols only (and only that symbols), so that when linking your program uses of symbols outside the 4.3 specs causes linkage errors.